# Compare 2 struct tm on multiplatform

Tags: c, linux, windows, linux-kernel

Lets say I have two

```
struct tm
```

I need to compare them in Linux, in Linux kernel and in Windows.
What is the best way to make cross-platform check?

By "compare" I mean finding out what date is bigger.
For example - I get date at this moment and compare it to date of some account expired.

Comment: You have to elaborate on what are your exact requirements, compare like `struct tm a, b; if (a == b) `?

Answer (score 10):

You could convert them with `mktime` to `time_t` and then calculate difference with `difftime`:

```
time_t t1 = mktime(tm1);
time_t t2 = mktime(tm2);
double diffSecs = difftime(t1, t2); // If positive, then tm1 > tm2
```

Comment: Is there a difftime in linux kernel and in windows? As I know - no. Read the question before low down karma..

Comment: @RedCollarPanda `difftime` is standard `time.h` function, so it's at least in Windows. Not sure what you mean about karma; I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Its also in linux, windows + linux + os-x meets my definition of multi-platform even if it proves not to be in the linux-kernel, whatever the asker meant by that. I'm voting this answer up as my google search on the title of the question was helped by the answer.

Also I feel classifying 'linux-kernel' as a platform is almost the same as classifying 'gimp' as a platform. So I'm downvoting the question

Comment: @user694733 I think you have it backwards: `difftime(t1, t2) > 0` means `tm1 > tm2`, not `tm2 > tm1`